# Accepting nested attributes in within a model, that contains other models not associated to itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

Okay I have a small issue which I'm not of. I know I'm close to solving this issue but I need some help. Okay so basically what I'm creating is a website that allows users to submit surveys, and then allow people to answer those surveys. So I created a survey model, which uses questions, and those questions use answers. When a user creates a survey he only creates the survey and the questions, the answers are later created through another model called results. What I'm having trouble doing is submitting those answers as part of the questions through the results form. So here is my results controller:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_result, only: [:show]

  def show
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
  end

  def new
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
    @survey.questions.all.each do |question|
      question.build_answer
    end 
    @result = @survey.results.build
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
    @result = @survey.results.build

    respond_to do |format|
      if @result.save
        format.html { redirect_to survey_result_path(@result), notice: 'Survey was successfully answered.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_result
      @result = Result.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def result_params
      params.require(:result).permit(:survey_id)
    end
end
```

So in my form I'm attempting to submit the answers as part of the questions and not the results.

Here's how that looks:

```
<%= form_for([@survey, @result]) do |f| %>
  <% if @result.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@result.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this result from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @result.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% for question in @survey.questions  %>   
    <div class="field">
      <label><%= question.question_content %></label>
        <%= fields_for :answer, question.build_answer do |builder| %>
          <%= builder.text_field :answer_content, placeholder: "Answer"%>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Anyway, this is the relevant part:

```
<% for question in @survey.questions  %>   
        <div class="field">
          <label><%= question.question_content %></label>
            <%= fields_for :answer, question.build_answer do |builder| %>
              <%= builder.text_field :answer_content, placeholder: "Answer"%>
            <% end %>
         </div>
```

I should also mention that, questions and answers have no controllers, they're only models, I don't need any views or controllers for them, there simply isn't any reason to have those components.

I don't know if it is an issue that the answers and questions are in no way related to the results. If it is better to change that then I'll do it, but so far this is the only issue I've come across with. If anyone can help me with this, I'd appreciate, this is the last step to a long difficult project.

Comment: For the sake of sanity and good design I would still consider having an answers controller which is responsible for taking feedback from the survey audience and then having a separate results controller which displays the results. Just because you can use nested attributes does not mean cramming everything into one controller is a good idea. If a controller is dealing with two resources that are not directly related - its usually a sign that it is doing far too much.

Comment: Also this is one topic that has been done to death - there are a billion questionnaire rails apps - take a look at a few and see how they solved the problem domain.

Comment: I have checked, and most of what I have, I have done by looking at those examples. Unfortunately this next part is not something I have found in any example so it basically fell to me to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking your word for it that you have tried @max's suggestion of looking how this has already been done - I agree with @max that seeing how people have already solved it will give you a better answer than what I've got for you. But, if you've tried that, then maybe this can help.

This is not an answer to your question, but it might be a solution to your problem. I agree with @max's first comment also - it seems like you're trying to do too much with that controller. If it were me, I would do some refactoring and take a look at your overall design rather than working through this specific problem.

Here's my suggestion. (Disclaimer: I haven't re-created your project to test it out, or provided enough detail for it to be a step-by-step instruction.) It is just one idea of another approach to the problem. I think it would make your issue go away by simplifying what each controller has to do.

## Suggestions

- Split up your controllers - `SurveysController` and `ResultsController` like @max suggested
- Associate the `Result` class with the `Survey` class (probably survey `has_many :results`, if one survey can be completed more than once)
- From a routing perspective, use [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) to have Results as a child of Survey (so your url might look like `http://yoursite.com/survey/12/result/2` to view the second set of answers to survey #12)
- From the Survey view, link to your new Result route as your "respond to the survey" link. In other words, answer a survey by creating a new Result that belongs_to the survey in question. This new result will be created, edited, and saved from a different controller than you use for the survey creation and management
- **Key part:** from the Result model, when you create a new result, use a callback to create one answer for every question in the associated survey (but leave the text of the answers empty for now) [See below for result.rb snippet]
- from the view, allow the user to provide text for each empty answer [See below for views/results/edit.html.erb snippet]
- when displaying the results, match the survey question ids to the result answer 
  ids

### in result.rb

```
after_initialize :create_answers

def create_answers
  return unless self.new_record? # don't create them if it isn't a new record
  self.survey.questions.each_with_index do |q,i|
    self.answers.create(question_index: i)
  end
end
```

### in views/results/edit.html.erb

```
<% @result.answers.each_with_index do |a,i| %>
  <!-- label the answer with: -->
  <%= @result.survey.questions[i] %>
  <!-- render the form field for: --> 
  <%= a.text %>
<% end %>
```

### from views/results/show.html.erb accessed from http://yoursite.com/survey/12/result/2

```
<dl>
<% @result.survey.questions.each_with_index do |q,i| %>
  <dt class="question"><%= q.text %></dt>
  <dd class="answer"><%= @result.answers[i] %></dd>
<% end %>
</dl>
```

## Summary

This lets you use the same basic controller logic for creating a survey that you would when saving the results. You let the model take care of matching questions to answers, and then the controller only has to deal with the result and it's child answers, or the survey and it's child questions.

Again, not a full solution, but hopefully some ideas to help you keep moving.

## Further Improvements

This is still a bit ugly - `@result.survey.questions[index]` isn't very clean. If it were me, I would get everything working, and then refactor the `@result.survey.questions[index]` stuff into the Result model somehow - maybe something like: `Result#question_answer_pairs` that returns a 2D array (but that's still not very clean). Or, use ActiveRecord to associate each answer with a corresponding question, so you can use `answer.text` and `answer.question_text` side by side.

Comment: These are some good ideas, I don't think I mentioned it or something, but yeah I do have two separate controllers, not just the one. The thing is that I was having trouble getting the results to store my answers, and I really didn't have an easy way to explain it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "trouble getting the results to store my answers"?

Comment: And specifically, how the results storing answers is different than surveys storing questions? Because you have the survey controller storing questions, right?

Comment: Well, when I need the person to answer a survey, they have to do so through the survey_results, so far it renders each survey's questions properly, but when it comes to the answers I'm just not sure on how to get the results form to store my answers. As you can see in my form, there are some answers created for those questions, the issue is that when I submit a result they're not being stored. Yes my survey controller does store the questions. I guess I could tie in the responses with the answers, but then how would I go about storing the question_id. This is my second time with rails.

Comment: Have you tried saving the result answers independent of the questions, like I suggested? It should be the same as saving the survey questions.

Comment: I see, I'd guess that I'd tie the answers to the results and then afterwards when it is time to display, them make a join between the survey and the results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92102/discussion-between-alexanderbird-and-argus).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I finally did it, and managed to tie the answers with the questions, by using some hidden fields, which I know is not the best way to do it, but I'm not really sure how else to make that work.